# How to avoid negative concentration from numerical solution using FDM scheme?

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics

$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + u \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} + w \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} = D \left(\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial y^2}\right)-C \cdot \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)$

How to avoid the negative concentration using FDM scheme?

Comment: Well, basically you are looking for a scheme that enforces the **maximum principle** and **non-negative constraint** for the advection-diffusion equation. I am not sure if it is possible to construct an FDM framework that satisfies those conditions or not.

Comment: These references might help: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/am/pii/S0045782516316176, https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/communications-in-computational-physics/article/abs/do-current-lattice-boltzmann-methods-for-diffusion-and-advectiondiffusion-equations-respect-maximum-principle-and-the-nonnegative-constraint/9C7EE980173524AA48C3DD852AFF7FA7, and https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/fld.2389

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some mistakes in your equation. You use y in some place and z in others. I suppose you are dealing with 2d flow.

You need a maximum principle. At the PDE level, the maximum principle holds if the velocity is divergence-free.

Assuming a divergence free velocity field, write an upwind scheme for convection terms and central scheme for diffusion. This is explicit in time scheme. Under a restriction in time step, you can show maximum principle. This will be only first order accurate though.

You can also use a central scheme for convection, in which case you will need a mesh Peclet number to be small enough to get maximum principle.